# IntelliSense in not working in Angular 10 with Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular10

Not able to import the files in Angular 10 using the Visual Studio Code. I have re-started the VS Code and even installed fresh copy but still, the issue not resolved. It looks like Angular 10 have some issue.

[image]

Comment: Able to import RouterModule but not able to import FormsModule, HttpClientModule.....tried in two systems.

Comment: Could this be a similar issue? Visual Studio doesn't like the tsconfig being split up. maybe VS Code is the same? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672746/vs-2019-no-intellisense-and-validation-after-ng-cli-update-to-version-10

Comment: Thanks Hockey J and HirenParekh, after moving tsconfig.base.json file stuff to tsconfig.json it started working.